# I want to do something after payment is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I created a payment function in my code using Stripe. The payment works well, it accept the money, but I want to introduce into an array some data after the payment is created otherwise if it fails to return to the page with a message.

I just created the function but I do not know what I should do after.

```
exports.postPayment = async (req,res,next) => {
    const loggedinUser = req.session.user._id;



const token = req.body.stripeToken;
    const charge = stripe.charges.create({
amount:200,
currency:'usd',
description:'Negative Comment',
source:token
    });


}
```

Should I create a then block or how I check if the payment was made. Now I'm in the test mode so all the payments will be accepted. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning. I.e. calling one of the return methods on the response 'res' parameter.

**Note!!** The first snipped makes the call to make payment, and returns immediately, i.e. the payment could succeed or fail, this snippet would not wait for the result, the second example would, utilising a promise.

```
exports.postPayment = async (req,res,next) => {
    const loggedinUser = req.session.user._id;

    const token = req.body.stripeToken;
    const charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount:200,
        currency:'usd',
        description:'Negative Comment',
        source:token
    });

    return res.status(200).json({message: "It works!"});
}
```

Unsure if charges.create returns a promise, but if it does, i'd do it like this:

```
exports.postPayment = async (req,res,next) => {
    const loggedinUser = req.session.user._id;

    const token = req.body.stripeToken;

    try {
        await const charge = stripe.charges.create({
            amount:200,
            currency:'usd',
            description:'Negative Comment',
            source:token
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: "An error occured!", error: e});
    }


    return res.status(200).json({message: "It works!"});
}
```